# Split lines layer into multiple parts using polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, polygon, clip, splitting

I have a polyline layer of rivers in England (one line, only attribute is length), and I need to divide it into regions so that I can work out the length of rivers in each region (the green bit is the line layer in the picture.

Is there a way to clip the line by the polygon layer, so that it creates one line per region? (a multi-part feature is fine)

[image]

Just to add - I've tried the clip tool, but it just clips to the outline of the whole polygon layer - so doesn't split up the regions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Intersect](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm) tool.

The Intersect tool takes the input features (your lines) and intersects them with your intersect features (your polygons) and outputs based on those polygon boundaries.

Also see [How Intersect Works](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/how-intersect-analysis-works.htm)

Example: In ArcMap I draw a handful of polygons, and some lines that crossed through them all.  I then ran the Intersect tool using the following settings:

[image]

And the result, with all lines split at boundaries:

[image]